# Cracks in my automatic texture in Unreal engine 5

Tags: textures, landscape, unreal-engine5

I am creating a custom landscape material, but there is a problem. I have rock and grass so when the ground is flat it should only show grass, but now I also get parts of the stone material on it.

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qB5L.jpg)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5t0sD.png)

[Material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkVru.png)

How do I make the code so it doesn't show the cracks on the top?